# Passing command-line options to dartvm in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to pass `--enable-vm-service` to the [dart VM](https://www.dartlang.org/server/tools/dart-vm) while running flutter but I didn't find any way to do it

simply running `flutter --enable-vm-service` returns

```
Could not find an option named "enable-vm-service".
```

I'm using android studio I would like to know if there a way to automatically pass the argument like this 
[image]
if not command line will be enough.

Comment: run `flutter run -h` command to see what can be passed as `"Additional arguments"`

Comment: I already did. and it didn't help `--enable-vm-service` is not a flutter command it is `dartvm` option

and flutter runs on `dartvm` surely there is a way to pass arguments to  `dartvm` from flutter.

Comment: if there is such a way it is hidden: official `flutter run` does  not seem to provide such an option

Comment: I think maybe even before `flutter run` there is a way to edit the `dartvm` with this option. I don't know I'm totally shooting in the dark here.

Comment: see `packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/commands/run.dart`

Answer (score 2):

The VM service runs automatically for Flutter, since Flutter uses it internally (eg. to send Hot Reload requests). If you run Flutter with `--start-paused` from the terminal for example, that will force it to print the VM service URL out:

```
To hot reload changes while running, press "r". To hot restart (and rebuild state), press "R".
An Observatory debugger and profiler on iPhone XS Max is available at: http://127.0.0.1:49303/
```

If you're running in VS Code, during a debug session there's a `Dart: Open Observatory` command that will launch the Observatory web app in your browser (this exposes the URL). There may be a similar button in IntelliJ/Android Studio, though I'm not sure.

You can also pass `--observatory-port` if you want to force a specific port:

```
flutter run --observatory-port 9999
```

In VS Code, you can add this to the `args` collection in your launch config (`.vscode/launch.json`). It'll probably also work in the args box shown in your screenshot for IntelliJ/Android Studio.

Comment: I think this didn't answer my question, I'm not asking about the `observatory` I'm asking how to command-line options to `dartvm`

Comment: I'm confused, you specifically said you wanted to pass `--enable-vm-service`. My answer explains why you don't need to, and how to get at the service that it enables.

Comment: Also, there are multiple VMs involved when you run `flutter run`.. there's the one running on the host machine (handling the build, etc.) and the one running on the device (running the app). Which are you trying to pass flags to?

Comment: I'm trying to pass the flag to the vm running on the device. is `observatory` passes `--enable-vm-service` internally.

Comment: @humazed I'm not sure why my answer doesn't do what you want. The VM service is already being started on the device, and the flag I gave lets you control the local port that will be forwarded to the device.

Comment: It would be great if you can also share how one can pass command line options to dartVM more generally (as per the title), as the title is very broad, and covers other arguments others might want to pass. I want to pass the `--root-certs-file`